# How to store files in cloud direclty from phonegap / ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cloud-storage

I'm developing an Ionic2 Android / iOS app, to create, save and sync cooking recipes.

Those recipes can have many images (ingredients) and to save server space / requirements, I'm planning to ask users for an account (dropbox, google drive, icloud) and folder to store those imagens.

Then to my server I will only send the public links to those images.

I've been searching but haven't found anything like that (plugin) and no one with this requirement / idea.
Only a few "file pickers / choosers" for dropbox but they are all old and they are just that, file pickers.

Is there a plugin for that?
If not, what would you recommend? Develop an interface with, for example, dropbox api?

I understand there are lots of things involved, like taking a picture without internet, that then needs to be synced to obtain public url, etc..

Thanks in advance